# Angular CLI HttpParams how to delete the params

Tags: angular-cli-v6

I am using angular CLI.
How to delete the token param name and value?

```
let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('siteId', 1);
    params = params.append('orgId', 2);
    params = params.append('token', 3);
```

This is my code so far:

```
validate(email) { 
  let params = new HttpParams(); 
  params = params.set('email', email); 
  params = params.set('siteId', this._global.SITEID); 
  params = params.set('orgId', this._global.ORGID); 
  params = params.set('domainName', this._global.DOMAIN_NAME); 
  params = params.set('token', this._global.getRandomUuid()); 
  params.delete('domainName',this._global.DOMAIN_NAME); 
  return this.api.call('member/duplicate', params); 
} 

call(url, params) { 
  // here I want to delete the token param name and value. 
}
```

Comment: maybe add some more information and context what you are doing and you might get answers. Your problem description seems quite minimalistic to me. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page

Answer (score 5):

`params.delete`:

> Construct a **new body** with either the given value for the given
>   parameter removed, if a value is given, or all values for the given
>   parameter removed if not.

Example:

`params = params.delete('token');`

Just writing `params.delete('token')` will not update the params object because `params` is immutable. The `delete` method does not modify the original object, but constructs new object with the param deleted.

Comment: It's not read-only. It was created using the `let` keyword not `const`

Comment: Thanks man! Your answer really helped me! I've never read the 'returns' section from documentation. After I've read your answer I checked the docs and yeah, there was all there :)) Thanks again!